# find tangent line of two adjacent circle

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, curve

[image]

those are 2 example cases of what I need to solve, it is just finding the **coordinate of D**, given position of A, and the direction vector of red and green line

- red/green line vector (or direction) is known
- point A is an intersection between the red line and red circle tangent point
- point B is the center of the red circle with radius = R (known)
- point C is an intersection between the green line and the green circle tangent point
- **point D is unknown and this one that needs to be calculated**
- point D will always located in green circle (radius of 2R from point B)
- both red and green line has the same radius of R
- V is the angle of the red line relative to north up
- W is the angle of the green line relative to north up
- the distance between point B and D is always 2R since the circle adjacent (touching each other)

much help and hint appreciated, preferred in some code instead of math equation

Comment: If you don't understand the mathematics, you will find the code very difficult to maintain.

Comment: Remember that SO is not a code writing service, so: how far did _you_ get already? Where's the code you already wrote to get you (part way) to solving the problem? And as mentioned, you're implementing a maths problem, so you better understand the maths, which means you almost certainly want to ask for maths help first (for which SO is not the right place but https://math.stackexchange.com is) and then once you undestand _that_, you should be able to implement the steps you now understand are required.

Comment: Without loss of generality make $V=0$, and $AB$ horizontal. This simplifies things as you can get rid of red line.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou remember that SO is not math.se, there is no LaTeX support here =)

Answer (score 2):

Having coordinates A,B,C, we can write two vector equations using scalar (dot) product:

```
AC.dot.DC = 0
DB.dot.DB = 4*R^2
```

The first one refers to perpendicularity between tangent to circle and radius to tangency point, the second one - just squared distance between circle centers.

In coordinates:

```
(cx-ax)*(cx-dx) + (cy-ay)*(cy-dy) = 0
(bx-dx)*(bx-dx) + (by-dy)*(by-dy) = 4*R^2
```

Solve this system for unknown `dx, dy` - two solutions in general case.

If A and C are not known, as @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans noticed:

Let

```
cr = sin(v)     sr = cos(v)
cg = sin(w)     sg = cos(w)
```

So

```
ax = bx + R * cr
ay = by + R * sr
```

and

```
dx = cx - R * cg
dy = cy + R * sg
```

Substituting expressions into the system above we have:

```
(dx+R*cg-bx-R*cr)*cg - (dy-R*sg-by-R*sr)*sg = 0
(bx-dx)*(bx-dx) + (by-dy)*(by-dy) = 4*R^2
```

Again - solve system for unknowns `dx, dy`

Comment: Note that as described, both C and D are unknown, not just D.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans   So known are only B, R and two directions?

Comment: A, R, red vector anchored at A and green vector anchored at A.

Comment: I made assumption that B is known, but it is not important - A defines B or B defines A.

Comment: exactly. We have A, we know R, so we know B. We don't have C or D, all we further know is that C is where the green line is tangent to the circle such that AC⟂CD, and CD is length R.

Comment: yes C is unknown, B can be calculated because A and r is known

Answer (score 2):

As a hint: draw it out some more:

[image]

We can construct D by constructing the line segment AG, for which we know both the angle and length, because  AC⟂AG, and the segment has length R.

We can then construct a line perpendicular to AG, through G, which gives us a chord on the blue circle, one endpoint of which is D. We know the distance from B to GD (because we know trigonometry) and we know that the distance BD is 2R (because that's a given). Pythagoras then trivially gives us D.

Comment: how do we know length of B to GD if angle of B or D is unknown

Comment: Because we know the angle of AC. That's one of the few things we start the exercise with knowing, so we can quite easily compute the distance from B to AC, and then just add R to that to get the distance from B to GD.

Answer (score 1):

You know where **A** is and the angle **θ** it makes from vertical.

[image: fig1]

So specify the line though **C** called `line(C)` above and the offset the line by **R** in order to get `line(D)` above that goes through point **D**.

In C# code this is

```
Line line_C = Line.ThroughPointAtAngle(A, theta);
Line line_D = line_C.Offset(radius);
```

Now find the intersection of this line to the greater circle

```
Circle circle = new Circle(B, 2 * radius);
if (circle.Intersect(line_D, out Point D, alternate: false))
{
    Console.WriteLine(D);
    float d_BD = B.DistanceTo(D);
    Console.WriteLine(d_BD);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Does not intersect.");
}
```

This produces point **D** either above `line(C)` or below `line(C)` depending on the `bool` argument `alternate`.

---

The code example below produces the following output:

```
D=Point(-0.4846499,-1.94039)
|BD|=2
```

The source code is

#### Program.cs

```
using static Float;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float radius = 1;

        Point A = new Point(-radius, 0);
        Point B = new Point(0, 0);

        float theta = deg(15);

        Line line_C = Line.ThroughPointAtAngle(A, theta);
        Line line_D = line_C.Offset(radius);

        Circle circle = new Circle(B, 2 * radius);
        if (circle.Intersect(line_D, out Point D, alternate: false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"D={D}");
            float d_BD = B.DistanceTo(D);
            Console.WriteLine($"|BD|={d_BD}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Does not intersect.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Point.cs

Describes a point in cartesian space using two coordinates `(x,y)`

```
using static Float;

public readonly struct Point
{
    readonly (float x, float y) data;

    public Point(float x, float y)
    {
        this.data = (x, y);
    }
    public static Point Origin { get; } = new Point(0, 0);
    public static Point FromTwoLines(Line line1, Line line2)
    {
        float x = line1.B * line2.C - line1.C * line2.B;
        float y = line1.C * line2.A - line1.A * line2.C;
        float w = line1.A * line2.B - line1.B * line2.A;
        return new Point(x / w, y / w);            
    }
    public float X => data.x;
    public float Y => data.y;

    public float SumSquares => data.x * data.x + data.y * data.y;

    #region Algebra
    public static Point Negate(Point a)
        => new Point(
            -a.data.x,
            -a.data.y);
    public static Point Scale(float factor, Point a)
        => new Point(
            factor * a.data.x,
            factor * a.data.y);
    public static Point Add(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(
            a.data.x + b.data.x,
            a.data.y + b.data.y);
    public static Point Subtract(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(
            a.data.x - b.data.x,
            a.data.y - b.data.y);

    public static float Dot(Point point, Line line)
        => line.A * point.data.x + line.B * point.data.y + line.C;

    public static Point operator +(Point a, Point b) => Add(a, b);
    public static Point operator -(Point a) => Negate(a);
    public static Point operator -(Point a, Point b) => Subtract(a, b);
    public static Point operator *(float f, Point a) => Scale(f, a);
    public static Point operator *(Point a, float f) => Scale(f, a);
    public static Point operator /(Point a, float d) => Scale(1 / d, a);
    #endregion

    #region Geometry

    public Point Offset(float dx, float dy)
        => new Point(data.x + dx, data.y + dy);
    public Point Offset(Vector2 delta) => Offset(delta.X, delta.Y);

    public float DistanceTo(Point point)
        => sqrt(sqr(data.x - point.data.x) + sqr(data.y - point.data.y));
    #endregion

    #region Formatting
    public string ToString(string formatting, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return $"Point({data.x.ToString(formatting, provider)},{data.y.ToString(formatting, provider)})";
    }
    public string ToString(string formatting)
        => ToString(formatting, null);
    public override string ToString()
        => ToString("g"); 
    #endregion

}
```

#### Line.cs

Describes a line in cartesian space using the coefficients `(a,b,c)` such that the equation of the line is **a** x + **b** y + **c** = 0

```
using static Float;

public readonly struct Line
{
    readonly (float a, float b, float c) data;

    public Line(float a, float b, float c) : this()
    {
        data = (a, b, c);
    }

    public static Line AlongX { get; } = new Line(0, 1, 0);
    public static Line AlongY { get; } = new Line(-1, 0, 0);

    public static Line ThroughPointAtAngle(Point point, float angle)
    {
        return new Line(cos(angle), -sin(angle), point.Y * sin(angle) - point.X * cos(angle));
    }
    public static Line ThroughTwoPoints(Point point1, Point point2)
        => new Line(
            point1.Y - point2.Y,
            point2.X - point1.X,
            point1.X * point2.Y - point1.Y * point2.X);

    public float A => data.a;
    public float B => data.b;
    public float C => data.c;

    #region Algebra

    public static float Dot(Line line, Point point)
        => line.data.a * point.X + line.data.b * point.Y + line.data.c;

    #endregion

    #region Geometry
    public Line ParallelThrough(Point point)
    {
        return new Line(data.a, data.b, -data.a * point.X - data.b * point.Y);
    }
    public Line PerpendicularThrough(Point point)
    {
        return new Line(data.b, -data.a, -data.b * point.X + data.a * point.Y);
    }
    public Line Offset(float amount)
        => new Line(data.a, data.b, data.c - amount * sqrt(sqr(data.a) + sqr(data.b)));

    public Line Offset(float dx, float dy)
        => new Line(data.a, data.b, data.c + data.a * dx + data.b * dy);

    public Line Offset(Vector2 delta) => Offset(delta.X, delta.Y);

    public float DistanceTo(Point point)
        => Dot(this, point) / (data.a * data.a + data.b * data.b);
    #endregion

    #region Formatting
    public string ToString(string formatting, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return $"Line({data.a.ToString(formatting, provider)}x+{data.b.ToString(formatting, provider)}y+{data.c.ToString(formatting, provider)}=0)";
    }
    public string ToString(string formatting)
        => ToString(formatting, null);
    public override string ToString()
        => ToString("g"); 
    #endregion
}
```

#### Circle.cs

Describes a circle using the center and radius.

```
using static Float;

public readonly struct Circle
{
    readonly (Point center, float radius) data;

    public Circle(Point center, float radius)
    {
        this.data = (center, radius);
    }

    public static Circle FromTwoPoints(Point point1, Point point2)
    {
        float radius = point1.DistanceTo(point2) / 2;
        Point center = (point1 + point2) / 2;
        return new Circle(center, radius);
    }

    public static Circle FromThreePoints(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3)
    {
        float k_1 = point1.SumSquares / 2;
        float k_2 = point2.SumSquares / 2;
        float k_3 = point3.SumSquares / 2;

        float dx_12 = point2.X - point1.X;
        float dy_12 = point2.Y - point1.Y;
        float dx_23 = point3.X - point2.X;
        float dy_23 = point3.Y - point2.Y;

        float det = dx_12 * dy_23 - dx_23 * dy_12;

        Point center = new Point(
            (dy_12 * (k_2 - k_3) + dy_23 * (k_2 - k_1)) / det,
            (dx_12 * (k_3 - k_2) + dx_23 * (k_1 - k_2)) / det);
        float radius = center.DistanceTo(point1);

        return new Circle(center, radius);
    }

    public Point Center => data.center;
    public float Radius => data.radius;

    #region Geometry

    public float DistanceTo(Point point)
        => data.center.DistanceTo(point) - data.radius;

    public float DistanceTo(Line line)
    {
        float d = line.DistanceTo(Center);
        if (d > 0)
        {
            return d - data.radius;
        }
        else
        {
            return d + data.radius;
        }
    }

    public bool Intersect(Line line, out Point point, bool alternate = false)
    {
        line = line.Offset(-Center.X, -Center.Y);
        int sign = alternate ? -1 : 1;
        float discr = sqr(line.A * data.radius) + sqr(line.B * data.radius) - sqr(line.C);
        if (discr >= 0)
        {
            float d = sign * sqrt(discr);
            float ab = line.A * line.A + line.B * line.B;
            point = new Point((line.B * d - line.A * line.C) / ab, -(line.A * d + line.B * line.C) / ab);
            point += Center;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            float ab = line.A * line.A + line.B * line.B;
            point = new Point((-line.A * line.C) / ab, -(+line.B * line.C) / ab);
            point += Center;
            return false;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region Formatting
    public string ToString(string formatting, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return $"Circle({data.center.ToString(formatting, provider)},{data.radius.ToString(formatting, provider)})";
    }
    public string ToString(string formatting)
        => ToString(formatting, null);
    public override string ToString()
        => ToString("g"); 
    #endregion

}
```

#### Float.cs

Helper functions dealing with `float` math which is lacking from `System.Math`.

```
public static class Float
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A factor of π.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The factor.</param>
    public static float pi(float x) => (float)(Math.PI * x);
    /// <summary>
    /// Degree to Radian conversion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The angle in degrees.</param>
    /// <returns>Angle in radians</returns>
    public static float deg(float x) => pi(x) / 180;
    /// <summary>
    /// Radian to Degree conversion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The angle in radians.</param>
    /// <returns>Angle in degrees</returns>
    public static float rad(float x) => x * 180 / pi(1);
    public static float sqr(float x) => x * x;

    public static float sqrt(float x) => (float)Math.Sqrt(x);
    public static float sin(float x) => (float)Math.Sin(x);
    public static float cos(float x) => (float)Math.Cos(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for all the answer (will upvote them), I did the work on it myself, I will share my result :

[image]

and here is length of d, to solve the equation :

[image]